# Ошибка при подключение Psycopg2 Python

Tags: python, psycopg2

При запуске возникает ошибка:

> conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync) psycopg2.OperationalError

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(host="localhost", dbname="MyData", user="postgres", password="1234")

cur=conn.cursor()

cur.execute("SELECT*FROM users;")

print(cur.fetchall())

conn.conmit()

cur.close()
```

Comment: `psycopg2.OperationalError` а дальше текст ошибки гадать?) Должно быть еще что то типо `FATAL:  текст ошибки`

Comment: @asanisimov, а дальше ничего не написано.

Comment: @MISHAELOVECHKIN, продолжайте дебажить. Проблем может быть множество.

Comment: @MISHAELOVECHKIN, нужна полная трасса стека ошибки, иначе непонятно в каком месте произошло и в чем причина. Проверьте что в `connect` все правильно передаете. Кроме того, это не относится к вашей текущей проблеме, но я бы запрос поменял `cur.execute("SELECT * FROM users")` и тут `conn.conmit()` ошибка в названии метода, должно быть `conn.commit()`